# Resize bitmap to fit full screen in custom view

Tags: android, image, bitmap, resize

I am trying to import an image from a photo path which I grab from another activity which I had the user choose the image from their gallery. I want the imported photo to resize and display on the full screen display custom view. I want the user to be able to draw on the full image. My issue that I am having is that when the image is imported, it is not resized to the screen size. I am using createscaledbitmap in onsizechanged using the w and h from the method but it still doesn't size it properly. Some photo fit the full screen (screenshots) but others which are taken from camera or downloaded either come out side ways or stretched out. I've been trying a bunch of things but can't seem to get it working. I want the image to be full screen so that the user can see the full photo and draw anywhere on it. Thank you to anyone who can help!

```
public class NewCropView extends View {
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();
private String myPath;
private Bitmap myBitmap, scaled;
private Canvas myCanvas;
Paint myBitmapPaint;
private boolean onEraseButton;

public NewCropView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    myPath = WelcomeActivity.myPhotoPath;


    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    myBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

}


/**
 * Method that changes the size when the canvas is first created. It is used so that
 * we can use a bitmap as the canvas and when the size changes it creates the bitmap as the canvas.
 * @param w
 * @param h
 * @param oldw
 * @param oldh
 */
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    Log.d("CutAdd", "This is my width in onSizedChanged: " + w);
    Log.d("CutAdd", "This is my height in onSizedChanged: " + h);

    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inMutable = true;
    myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myPath, o);
    scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, w, h, true);
    myCanvas = new Canvas(scaled);
}

/**
 * Method that creates the new canvas with the paint / path so user can draw on the canvas.
 * @param canvas
 */
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, myBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

/**
 * Method for user touch events, for when they are paining / touching on the screen it follows.
 * @param motionEvent
 * @return
 */
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent)
{
    float touchX = motionEvent.getX();
    float touchY = motionEvent.getY();

    switch(motionEvent.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
    }
    invalidate();
    getTrue();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: no, no, no, dont scale the Bitmap only if you want it to be larger/smaller on the screen, use Canvas.drawBitmap with a Matrix parameter or use Canvas.scale() method

Comment: Are you saying inside my onSizedChanged on in my onDraw method? I tried doing both ways but can't seem to get it to work. I tried canvas.scale() using the w, h from onSizedChanged but still came out sideways. Then for Canvas.drawBitmap I don't see how to get the Matrix to use the Matrix.scaletofit.center since it is wanting only a parameter of Matrix. I'm still new to android so I'm still trying to learn! I appreciate your help.

Comment: setup the Matrix in onSizeChanged and use it in onDraw

Comment: You used a Matrix or canvas scaling?

Comment: I used the Matrix in a separate method and it worked perfectly!